# How to add duplicate rows, but add values in one column in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

So this is the dataframe that I'm working on.
As you can see there are duplicate rows with exactly the same values.
I want to know how to merge these rows into one single row. However, there is one more condition. At the far right column(not in the picture), there is a column called 'amount' which includes the amount of money that customers spent in each purchase. I want to merge duplicate rows, but add the amount value in each row.

```
joined <- inner_join(customers, payments, by = 'customerNumber')
```

[image: A]

Comment: `aggregate(amount ~ customerNumber, joined, sum)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (I could not try it on your data since you only provided a picture but it should work):

```
library(dplyr)
joined %>% group_by_at(vars(-amount)) %>% # group by all columns except amount
           summarise(amount=sum(amount)) # get sum of amount by group
```

Comment: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
I got this error trying.

Comment: Hum, could you try this in R to see if it comes from your dataframe? `mtcars %>% group_by_at(vars(-mpg)) %>% summarise(mpg=sum(mpg))`

Comment: Also what's the result of `class(joined)`?

Comment: joined is data frame and the mtcars line show some result,but i have no idea what they are...

Comment: install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)
getwd()
customers <- read.csv('customers.csv')
customers
payments <- read.csv('payments.csv')
payments
joined <- inner_join(customers, payments, by = 'customerNumber')
joined

Comment: Could you please add to your post the result of `dput(head(joined,10))`? Thanks. The mtcars test was to see if you had the correct version of `dplyr`, it seems ok

Comment: Actuaally  i figured it out the problem was that i had some columns other than amount that had different columns. After dropping those columns, your code worked and i got the result. Thanks a lot